# Zabbix : Registering host with the same IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, zabbix

We are using AWS CloudFormation with Static Private IP to deploy services i.e every time we deploy we bring down a instance with a IP and spawn a new one with the same IP. We are using Zabbix for monitoring and the hostname for the instance is ip-aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd.us-west-2.compute.internal (where aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd is the IP). Everything worked fine when it was deployed for the first time, but from the 2nd deployment, zabbix-agent registration started failing, stating that the host with the same hostname exists in Zabbix. Is there a way to solve this ?

Comment: When you say `bring down`, do you mean `stopped` or `terminated`?

Comment: bring down means terminated

Comment: Are you using auto-registration?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using auto-registration in Zabbix here.
The unique ID for a host in Zabbix is it's (technical) [name](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/hosts/host#configuration), the IP address actually doesn't have to be unique per host.

So, the problem you are facing is that AWS actually uses the IP in the naming scheme for the instance. Reusing an IP means reusing a hostname.

There are ways to work around this:

- After decommissioning an AWS instance make sure it is cleared from Zabbix as well. You could use an [API call](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/api/reference/host/delete) from you orchestration tooling to achieve this, or you could do it manually if the decommissioning is being done manually as well.
- Instead of using the AWS hostname as the technical name in Zabbix, use something else which is unique. Perhaps you can have your orchestration tool set the hostname parameter in the `zabbix_agentd.conf` file to something more unique you can control and is more logical. (i.e. web-server-001).
- You can use a little trick with the `HostnameItem` agent configuration parameter using a `system.run[]` item key to grab a unique identifier from the system itself, like the ec2 instance-id using the `ec2-metadata` cli tool. You can then make the host more recognizable by providing a human readable Visible name in Zabbix.

Answer (score 1):

dont have experience in zabbix but have had the similar issue with other tools (udeploy/centrify) sometimes. Since you are re-using the ip and hostname you should look in to de-register the instance from zabbix when the instance is terminated, if there is an api call for that then you could add that to your auto scaling life cycle groups for doing the de-registration automatically ( provided you use scaling)

Answer (score 0):

You can have different names for your computer and zabbix config file

So, if your (real) computer name is `ip-aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd.us-west-2.compute.internal` you can write another name in zabix_agentd.conf (zabbix agent config file, something like:

```
Hostname=new1.ip-aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd.us-west-2.compute.internal
```

Change this name after up your server and before start zabbix agent

If you don't want to change the hostname in Zabbix, you have to disable the auto registration feature or try comment the HostMetadata and HostMetadataItem on zabbix_agentd.conf